# How to convert unicode codepoint like U+1F4DB to char?

Tags: delphi, unicode

I have in string a code point like `U+1F4DB` and I would like to convert it to a unicode char (). How to do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't convert that to a single `char`. That code point is outside of the range that can be represented in UTF-16 as a single 16 bit element. Instead it is represented by a surrogate pair, two `char` elements. In Delphi it would be expressed as the string

```
#$D83D#$DCDB
```

as can be discerned from this page: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f4db/index.htm

In practise I think it would be simpler to paste the character into your source code, inside a string literal, and let the source code be stored encoded as UTF-8. The IDE will prompt to do so automatically. That is represent it as

```
''
```

---

In comments you make it clear that you wish to parse arbitrary text of the form U+xxxx. Extract the numeric value and convert it to an integer. Then pass it through [`TCharHelper.ConvertFromUtf32`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Character.TCharHelper.ConvertFromUtf32).

Comment: thanks david, ok, but how to convert u+xxx to a unicode char (or string) ? i have only the string literal u+xxxx that i need to convert

Comment: Read the utf-16 spec spec then. Parse the code point value to an integer. If it can be expressed as a single char, it's simple, otherwise follow the surrogate pair rules.

Comment: i found, it's Tcharacter.ConvertFromUtf32 :) it's return a string

Comment: @andrey: to get the integer to pass to `ConvertFromUtf32()`, replace the `U+` portion with `$` and then pass the string to `StrToInt()`, eg: `ConvertFromUtf32(StrToInt(StringReplace('U+1F4DB', 'U+', '$', [])))`. And `TCharacter` is deprecated and replaced with `TCharHelper`