# How to assign (display) Unicode UTF-32 (Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs) to TLabel.Caption?

Tags: delphi, unicode, label, caption

I want to display  ([U+1F4CD - round pushpin](http://www.unicode-symbol.com/u/1F4CD.html)) in a `TLabel` caption (`lblLocation`) displaying something like : `" Pretoria, South Africa"`, but I keep getting a weird block-like thing instead.

I have tried pasting the character directly into my source code, but this also results in a weird block-like thing (my source code is UTF-8 encoded).

Before Pasting :

[image]

Directly after pasting :

[image]

I have also tried using `ConvertFromUtf32()`, per [How to convert unicode codepoint like U+1F4DB to char?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45919526/).

```pascal
lblLocation.Caption := lblLocation.Caption + ConvertFromUtf32(StrToInt('$1F4CD'));
```

Running the above code gives this in the caption of the `TLabel`:

[image]

Comment: You can use charmap (on Windows) to verify if the label's font contains the character.

Comment: As for the assignment, `lbLocation.Caption + #$1F4CD` is fine.

Comment: `ConvertFromUtf32(StrToInt('$1F4CD'))` - you don't need `StrToInt()`, you can use an integer hex literal instead: `lbLocation.Caption := ConvertFromUtf32($1F4CD) + ' Pretoria, South Africa';` Or, just use UTF-16 char literals: `lbLocation.Caption := #$D83D#$DCCD' Pretoria, South Africa';`

Comment: @Remy - `Length(#$1F4CD)` returns 2, the  assignment in my comment works.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I didn't say `#$1F4CD` doesn't work. Although, using hex values > 4 digits is undocumented. Up to 4 digits is documented as 1 `WideChar`, there is no mention of > 4 digits producing 2 `WideChar`s. If it works, great. Maybe it is a new feature, I'm sure that didn't always work in early Unicode-enabled versions of Delphi.

Answer (score 5):

The character that you are trying to display does not have a glyph in the font that you are using. You need to find a font that does have a glyph for this character.